# How to add a conditional statement (Using an element ID as condition) to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements, element

Again, I have another basic question for the wonderful users here at StackOverflow. I am new to client-side programming and although this is a fairly basic example in other languages I know, I am unsure of the proper syntax of doing so here (if it has been implemented).

Here is my current code. The page, for reference, can be found at http://paysonfirstassembly.com/. However, I have not uploaded the most recent version and the function below does not exist on the production server (yet).

```
$(function () {
    var $subnavContainer = $(".subwrapperBlue");
    $(".navElements").click(function () {
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
    });
```

This is my most recently updated code. The div will not reappear after clicking, however, the alert box DOES pop up.

```
var $subnavContainer = $(".subwrapperBlue");
$(function () {
    $(".navElements").click(function () {
        switch ($(this).index()) {
            case 0:
                $subnavContainer.html("some html");
                break;
            case 1:
                $subnavContainer.html("some more html");
                break;
            case 2:
                $subnavContainer.html("some other html");
                break;
            case 3:
                $subnavContainer.html("the final html");
                break;
        }
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
        alert("this works");
    });
```

Comment: Mind if I see your html?

Comment: The site's link is in the second paragraph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the index of the element. It starts with `0` as the first, `1` as the second, etc.:

```
if ($(this).index() == 0) {
  $subnavContainer.html("some html");
}
```

`$(this)` refers to the element which was clicked.

---

Instead of doing a long `if {} else if {} ...` chain, why not use a `switch`? It's much neater IMO as you can inline the `break;`:

```
switch ($(this).index()) {
  case 0:
    $subnavContainer.html("some html");
    break;

  case 1:
    $subnavContainer.html("some more html");
    break;

  ...
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the simplest solution. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: No problem. I'd consider reading a simple jQuery introduction, as it has basically everything you need to get started: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Haha, wonderful. I was sure there would be a general tutorial on JavaScript, jQuery, or both; but this community is just too darn helpful that I didn't need to look one up!

Comment: I've updated my question with the most recent version of the JavaScript. However, I encounter an error, where the div will not reappear.

Comment: Can you post the error? I've update my answer a little. Just some syntax suggestions.

Comment: For some reason I can't edit my comment, so I suppose I'll just add a new one... I unfortunately need to be heading off to bed! However, I've updated the code on the production environment (http://paysonfirstassembly.com/) in the hopes that you may further assist me with this issue.


Thank you SO much! I appreciate your help more than you can imagine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function () {
    var $subnavContainer = $(".subwrapperBlue");
    $(".navElements").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target.id == 'firstElement')
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some html");
        }
        else if (e.target.id == 'secondElement')
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some other html");
        }
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    var $subnavContainer = $(".subwrapperBlue");
    $(".navElements").click(function (event) { <-- CHANGED
        var el = event.target;
        if (el.id == #firstElement)
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some html");
        }
        else if (el.id == #secondElement)
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some other html");
        }
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
    });
```

That's so you can get access to the [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target)

Alternately, use `$(this)` to test the element that you clicked on. It really just kind of depends on what you're starting with.

```
$(function () {
    var $subnavContainer = $(".subwrapperBlue");
    $(".navElements").click(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == #firstElement)
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some html");
        }
        else if ($(this).attr('id') == #secondElement)
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some other html");
        }
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
    });

$(function () {
    var $subnavContainer = $(".subwrapperBlue");
    $(".navElements").click(function () { 
        if ($(this).index() == 0)
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some html");
        }
        else if ($(this).index() == 1) // zero based indexing
        {
            $subnavContainer.html("some other html");
        }
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
    });
```

Comment: If you view the webpage in the URL I gave you, you will see that the class ".navElements" is used to style each individual Main Navigation component.

EDIT: Is it possible to use $(this.elementID), if (this) is a selector with a class reference?

Comment: @Penumbra you may not realized I updated my answer after I reread your question. I just wanted to give you a couple of options on ways to approach the problem.

Comment: @Penumbra no, you can't do `$(this.elementID)`* but you can do `$(this).attr('id')` or `var that = $(this); that.id ...` ~ *if you can I didn't know you could ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you HTML looks like this

```
<div id='firstElement' nave' class='navElements">Elem 1</div>
<div id='secondElement' class='navElements">Elem 2</div>
<div id='thirdElement' class='navElements">Elem 3</div>
<div id='fourthElement' class='navElements">Elem 4</div>
```

You can simply do this

```
$(".navElements").click(function () {
   var $id = $(this).attr('id');
   if ($id == 'firstElement') {
     //code
   } elseif ($id == 'secondElement') {
     //code
   }
   //more code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are alreayd a few good answers but another way would be having two methods

```
$(function () {
    var $subnavContainer = $(".subwrapperBlue");
    $(".navElements").first().click(function () {
        $subnavContainer.html("some html");

        //This element is hidden onLoad using the $(document).ready object.
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
    });

    $(".navElements").not(":first").click(function () {
        $subnavContainer.html("some other html");

        //This element is hidden onLoad using the $(document).ready object.
        $subnavContainer.show("slow");
    });
});
```